# Joint cdf (please help)

Tags: probability

Suppose X and Y have a joint pdf
$$
f(x,y) =
\left\{
\begin{array}{cc} 2x+2y ~&\text{if}~ 0 \leq x \leq y \leq 1 \\
0 &~\text{ otherwise} \end{array}
\right. 
$$
What is the Joint CDF and marginal CDF?

I tried to find it (the answer that I got for the joint CDF is $x^2y+xy^2$) but I’m not really sure. Also can someone please tell me how to select the bounds that we use to integrate the pdf for continuous r.v? Sometimes I got stuck on how to decide the limit of integration that we have to use

Comment: The CDF is $F(x,y) = x_0y_0(x_0+y_0)$ if $x,y>0$, where $x_0 = \min\{x,1\}$ and $y_0 = \min\{y,1\}$, and zero otherwise.

Comment: What’s that mean? Is min means minimum? Can you be more specific? thank you

Comment: I missed that $y\ge x$. So I calculated again and found$$F(x,y) = \begin{cases}0 & \text{if $x\le 0$ or $y\le 0$}\\\min\{y,1\}^3 & \text{if $0 < x\le\min\{y,1\}$}\\x^3+\min\{y,1\}x^2+\min\{y,1\}^2x & \text{if $0 < \min\{y,1\} < x$}\end{cases}.$$This comes from the representation$$F(x,y) = 2\int_0^{\min\{y,1\}}\int_0^{\min\{x,t\}}(s+t)\,ds\,dt.$$

Comment: This is probably a dumb question but I don’t really get the concept and meaning of min {a,b}

Comment: Hmm, well, if you have two numbers $a$ and $b$, then $\min\{a,b\}$ is the smaller one of these two numbers. If $a=b$, then $\min\{a,b\} = a = b$.

Comment: Thank you. And to find the marginal cdf f(x), we have to use thispiecewise thing also?